# Create and jump to Spock unit test for a Java class in Idea IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

Is there a way to create and jump to Spock unit test for an application written in Java in Idea IDE ([it's working fine for a Groovy app](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-groovy-tests-and-navigating-to-tests.html))? The project is Maven based if it matters.

Reason: I'd like to use Spock framework to test my Java app.

Comment: I have used the same approach for writing Spock tests of Java and Groovy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out by myself the steps to make it work:

1. Add the following plugins to the POM file:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.18.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <includes>
               <include>**/*Test.java</include>
               <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
           </includes>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
       <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.5</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                   <goal>testCompile</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Create `src/test/groovy` directory
3. Install [GMavenPlus IntelliJ Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7442?pr=idea)
4. If Idea still doesn't see `src/test/groovy` as a source directory you could delete all the Idea project files from you hard-drive and import your Maven project again

After that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will offer you to create new tests either in `src/test/java` (should be chosen for JUnit tests) or in `src/test/groovy` (should be chosen for Spock tests).

P.S. command line `mvn clean test` also works correctly running both JUnit and Spock.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is the default shortcut for unit test creation / navigation (at least on Windows). It can be checked/changed from `File` -> `Settings` -> `Keymap` then in the tree select `Navigation` -> `Test` (you can also filter the key map to find it easier)

[image: IJ test navigation keymap]

This opens a dedicated popup which allow you to either create a new unit test, or jump to existing ones (if any).

This goes for groovy...

[image: IJ groovy unit test navigation]

... or java

[image: IJ java unit test navigation]

Comment: Your Groovy test are located in src/test/java which is not a preferred way to go. Thanks for the effort anyways!